# pandas code not executed in py2exe...I think?

Tags: python, csv, py2exe

Python n00b here. I wrote the following code which works on its own. This script processes a small batch of csv files. After a CSV file has been added, the script sorts them and adds "_sorted" to the filename. The script removes any existing csv files with "_sorted" in the filename before processing the newly-added files.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
directory = "C:\Path\to\csvfiles"
output = "C:\Path\to\csvfiles"
csvfiles = os.path.join(directory, '*.csv')
for csvfile in glob.glob(csvfiles):
    filename = os.path.basename(csvfile)
    if '_sorted' in filename:
        print "Remove this file"
        os.remove(csvfile)

for csvfile in glob.glob(csvfiles):
    filename = os.path.basename(csvfile)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df = df[df["ORGANIZATION"]!="WPPL"]
    df = df.sort('MEETING START TIME')
    #write new csv file
    df.to_csv(filename + '_sorted.csv', cols=["DATE","MEETING START TIME","MEETING END TIME","DESCRIPTION","ORGANIZATION","LOCATION"],index=False)
```

The problem I'm having is, I created an executable via py2exe. When I run the executable, the "sorted" files are removed, but the new files are not created; so it appears to me that the pandas-related code isn't getting run.

The code for my script that calls py2exe follows, if that might be helpful:

```
import numpy
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=["pandastest3.py"])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my above code was resolved by changing the line

```
filename = os.path.basename(csvfile)
```

to

```
 filename = csvfile
```